# getting a 403 error from youtube data API

Tags: api, youtube-data-api

I'm getting a 403 error from youtube data API.
Its confusing because I'm getting that my credinal key isn't enabled but in the developer console the key is enbaled, and I'm getting 100% errors.

[image: Browser error message]
[image: errors at google developer console]
[image]

Comment: I was using a wrong link address

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the http://localhost:3000/ restriction from the website restrictions

Answer (score 0):

My youtube project was corrupted, i deleted it and created a new one and it worked.